# Delete all occurrences of ObjectId in arrays

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schema:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {type: String, required: true},
    favouriteItems: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Item'}],
    userItems: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Item'}]
});

var itemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    price: {type: Number, required: true}
});

mongoose.model('User', userSchema , 'Users');
mongoose.model('Item', itemSchema , 'Items');
```

When I delete the item, I want to remove its ObjectId from `favouriteItems` and `userItems` from all users whose array contains it.

**Example:**

Initial:

```
Users:
[
    {
        _id: "a",
        username: "username1",
        favouriteItems: ["id1"],
        userItems: ["id2", "id3"]
    },
    {
        _id: "b",
        username: "username2",
        favouriteItems: ["id2"],
        userItems: ["id1", "id4"]
    },
    ...
]

Items:
[
    {
        _id: "id1",
        name: "item1",
        price: 19
    },
    {
        _id: "id2",
        name: "item2",
        price: 7
    },
    ...
]
```

When I remove item with id `id1` I want the following result (`id1` must be removed from arrays `favouriteItems` and `userItems` of all users):

```
Users:
[
    {
        _id: "a",
        username: "username1",
        favouriteItems: [],
        userItems: ["id2", "id3"]
    },
    {
        _id: "b",
        username: "username2",
        favouriteItems: ["id2"],
        userItems: ["id4"]
    },
    ...
]

Items:
[
    {
        _id: "id2",
        name: "item2",
        price: 7
    },
    ...
]
```

How do I achieve this using **mongoose** and **node.js**?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the `post` [mongoose middleware hooks](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) and specifically the hook on `remove`:

```
itemSchema.post('remove', async function(doc) {
  // doc is removed ... execute query to remove from favorites using the `doc._id`
});
```

Comment: Does there exist any other option (for example first finding all users who have ItemId in their arrays and then removing it)?

Comment: Sure but why do you need to have 2 steps where you can achieve the same in one?